# NLog with Postsharp not logging

Tags: c#, aop, nlog, postsharp

I found out what the problem is. There is no problem with the code. The problem that I wrote column name incorrect in the query. I do not know how I missed such a thing, but thank you for all your help. You can use the codes for the NLog if you want.

( I trying to Logging with NLog into AOP. I working Winform and using Postsharp. NLog codes into ExceptionLoggingAttribute.cs . This codes studies in Form1.cs but does not working in Aspect. Please Help me! )

AOP inside

```cs
namespace LogLibrary
{
    [PSerializable]
    public class ExceptionLoggingAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
    {
        public FlowBehavior flowbehavior { get; set; }
        public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            NLog.Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("databaseLogger");
            logger.Error(args.Exception.Message);
            logger.Fatal(args.Exception.Message);
            logger.Debug(args.Exception.Message);
            logger.Trace(args.Exception.Message);
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
        }
  }
```

Nlog.Config İnside

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">


  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>


  <targets>

    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"

      connectionStringName="NLogConn"

      commandText="exec dbo.dlog @username,@ErrorName,@MethodName,@StackName, @Date_Time">

      <parameter name="@username" layout="${identity}"/>
      <parameter name="@ErrorName" layout="${message}"/>
      <parameter name="@MethodName" layout="${machinename}"/>
      <parameter name="@StackName" layout="${stacktrace}"/>
      <parameter name="@Date_Time" layout="${date}"/>

    </target>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="databaseLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

App.Config İnside

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NLogConn" connectionString="Data Source=DMGM0349997\MSSQLSERVER01; Initial Catalog=deneme; Integrated Security=true;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Form1 inside

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PostSharp.Aspects;
using NLog;
using LogLibrary;


namespace LogApp
{
    [ExceptionLogging]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("bla bla");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this photo helps you for understand me

[image: Solution]

Comment: Is your code entering the aspect code?

Comment: Yes, but does not working.

Comment: please explain "does not work". What are you expecting? What is the current result?

Comment: I want to save the error information in the database when the program fails. But this process must be in the aspect

Comment: Did you verify your internal log : c:\temp\nlog-internal.log , to see what NLog is trying to do. It is a verbose kind of logging which contains all the information on what NLog is doing. So better have a look at that. It will also record any exceptions that are occurring while NLog tries to log something

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but i could not find the file you said.

Comment: I found out what the problem is.
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable first the internal log, set `internalLogLevel` on "info":

```
internalLogLevel="Info" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log"
```

If there is still no internalLogFile, then NLog can't find you nlog.config. Check the location of nlog.config.

Alternative you read it config like this:

```
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("pathTo_Nlog.config")
```

Or set-up the config on C#

Comment: I have nlog.config into my app file but i didn't have nlog-internal.log file. Also NLog works in Form1.cs  but not in Aspect codes. (NLog attached Aspect Library)

Comment: I found out what the problem is. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope this photo helps you for understand me

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question instead of giving information in an answer

Comment: Can you please delete this "answer"? I embedded the photo for you in the question. Just accept my edit :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I executed my C# console app's main method that contained codes below, does not any log created:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger<Program>();

Log.Info("Application Started . . .");
```

My problem was the location of NLog.config file.

I right clicked and selected Properties NLog.config in Visual Studio. Then for "Copy to Output Directory" property, selected "**Copy if newer**" option.

The problem was that NLog.config file was not in executing directory of my app.

This [page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file) describes how to configure NLog via XML specification.
specially read the Log Location section.

My AppConfig :

```
<sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging"/>
</sectionGroup>
<common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog444">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE"/>
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
```

and NLog.config files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="d:\NLog_Internallog.txt">
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="logs" />
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
         name="fileXmlName"
         header="&lt;nlog&gt;"
         footer="&lt;/nlog&gt;"
         fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}.log.xml"
         concurrentWrites="true"
         createDirs="true"
         autoFlush="true">
      <layout xsi:type="Log4JXmlEventLayout">
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="fileXmlName" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```